# Query Active Directory and Export using VBScript/WSH

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, wsh

I want to query a AD server to get certain fields using VBScript or WSH script

These fields

> - DN
> - userid
> - mail
> - company
> - displayName

And export/output the fields to a text file.

How can I accomplish that?

I came from linux background and need this as the computer that will run the script is running windows

Using linux,

```
`ldapsearch -x -h hostserver -b "cn=contacts,dc=support,dc=com" CN="name"`
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual method is to use ADO and an [LDAP query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205) to retrieve information about AD objects:

```
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

base   = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))"
attr   = "distinguishedName,userid,mail,company,displayName"
scope  = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  'do stuff with rs.Fields(fieldname).Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

conn.Close
```

As you can see there is a lot of boilerplate code involved, so I wrote [this class](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml) (`ADQuery`) to simplify the handling. The README contains some examples.

If you already know the distinguished name of an object you can also directly retrieve it like this:

```
dn = "CN=Joe User,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
Set user = GetObject("LDAP://" & dn)
WScript.Echo user.Get("displayName")
WScript.Echo user.Get("mail")
...
```

Comment: Error occurred. The directory property cannot be found in the cache.

Comment: its fixed but how i check if the dn has the property like some dn has mail, some dont

Comment: Try `IsEmpty()` to check if the attribute has a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
attr = "distinguishedName,userid,mail,company,displayName"
```

userid is not part of AD, it is sAMAccountName

```
Set cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope
```

cmd.CommandText is not an object, it is only:
    cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DirectoryServices [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx). This will give you access to the AD and the required AP to query it.
[Directory Searcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) object can be used to quert the AD and it returns a [SerchResult collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection.aspx). You can then read the values out of that as strings, easily writable into a text file. Hope this was helpful!